# How to connect an Android phone to PC for internet via USB

Tags: usb, internet

I need to share the internet connection of the PC with the smartphone, using a USB cable, is it possible to do that?

My router has some problems and the WiFi doesn't work. But on my computer, the internet works.

My phone is a Honor 7s

The Android version is 8.1.0

Comment: Check this [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/163358/247431)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but you need to root your device.

The Android kernel supports it, simply there is no option to do that in the GUI.

There are also apps to do it, but all of them requires root privilege.

The other direction (sharing your wifi or mobile network for a computer connected with usb) works seamlessly.